# Why is it not possible to use implicitly typed function arguments with explicitly typed function arguments?

Tags: c, syntax-error

If i were to compile the below code:

```c
// x is implicitly typed as int
void foo(x, char y) {
    return;
}
```

A syntax error would occur (`expected identifier`), but i am not sure why this syntax is not valid.

However:

```c
void foo(int x, char y) {
    return;
}
```

compiles successfully.

So why is this syntax not valid?
I am no expert at C so i'm not sure if this is a silly question or not.

Comment: Because it's not valid C syntax.

Comment: Ironically, I think this would be valid C90 syntax.

Comment: If you're just learning C, then forget about implicit declarations entirely.  They are completely obsolete, and problematic even where they are still allowed.  The only acceptable reason to be thinking about them is if you are a language lawyer interested in extreme minutae, or if you are actually living in the early '80s and are posting through a wormhole in time and space :)

Comment: @NateEldredge I just asked the question because i stumbled across implicit types and i just thought "maybe i could use it"

Comment: Sure, I'm only joking and it's a perfectly fine question.  But if you're wondering whether you can or should use implicit declarations in your own code, the answer for all intents and purposes is a big NO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implicit argument types, or more accurately a function definition with an identifier list, was part of the original K&R design of C.  In those days, you could either have a definition like this:

```
int foo(x, y) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

In which case all parameters default to type `int`, or a set of declarations before the body:

```
int foo(x, y) 
   int x;
   char *y;
{
    return 0;
}
```

To specify the types of the arguments.  In neither case were the types of the parameters known to the caller.

Specifying the types directly in the definition was added to the language later, which also added the ability to specify the types of a function's arguments in a declaration, allowing callers to know the types of the parameters.

So there's wasn't much reason to have a hybrid of the two, as one was made to improve on the other.

Comment: So implicit types are just a old feature that just stayed in the language ever since just like the `auto` keyword

Comment: @nameless_user Consider when C was developed, memory cost a $ for a few _bytes_.  Short cuts were used that have no place today.

Comment: @nameless_user C does not have an auto keyword.

Comment: @SafelyFast Actually it does, though it can only be applied to local variables making it superfluous.

Comment: Wow I learned something new. Thanks. Next time I’ll do my research before I post a comment like that!

Comment: There is no dichotomy as presented in this answer; `int foo(x, y) { … }` and `int foo(x, y) int x; char *y; { … }` are not two different ways of defining a function. They are one way, a function with an identifier list, and any parameter not declared in the delaration list defaults to `int`. That can be any number of parameters from zero to all of them, not just zero or all. That is per the C 1990 standard. In C 1999 and beyond, all parameters must be declared in the declaration list; you could not have either zero or any number less than all of them declared.

Comment: That is K&R too; page 205 of the first edition says “Any identifiers whose type is not given are taken to be `int`”, and there is no requirement that it be all or none.